# How to select non empty value for columns from each group?

Tags: sql, group-by

I have the following table.

```
| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 |
| ---- | ---- | ---- | ---- |
| 123  | 345  | LA   | 001  |
| 123  | 345  | AB   |      |
| 123  | 345  | LA   |      |
| 123  | 345  |      |      |
| abc  | cde  | LA   |      |
| abc  | cde  |      |      |
| abc  | cde  | AB   |      |
| abc  | cde  | LA   |      |
| ooo  | zzz  | LA   |      |
| ooo  | zzz  | LA   | 001  |
| ooo  | zzz  | LA   |      |
| ooo  | zzz  | LA   | 001  |
| 12   | 35   | LA   |      |
| 12   | 35   | LA   |      |
| 12   | 35   | LA   |      |
| 12   | 35   | LA   |      |
```

I would like to select for each group of `col1` & `col2`, `col3` must be `AB` if it is present in the group, else `blank`, and `col4` should be the `non-blank` if `non-blank` value is present, else it should be `blank`. `col4` for each group will either have a `unique non-blank` value or `blank`.

Desired output:

```
| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 |
|------|------|------|------|
| 123  | 345  | AB   | 001  |
| abc  | cde  | AB   |      |
| ooo  | zzz  |      | 001  |
| 12   | 35   |      |      |
```

---

Desired code:

```
select col1, col2,
(AB if AB present else blank) as col3,
(non-blank value if non-blank is present else blank) as col4
from test
group by col1, col2;
```

---

What I have tried so far:

```
select col1, col2,
max(col4) as col4
from test
group by col1, col2;
```

I don't know how to do it for `col3`

SQL Fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dtEiDdu6Arn6VQTGwMXm4q/0

NOTE:

1. I require a vendor agnostic solution. I *think* an RDBMS specific solution *might* work in the platform I use, but I would have to test out that answer/solution and get back to you though.
2. I am not querying from the source, but from a grid, so I am not using an RDBMS at the backend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the column `col3` you need a `CASE` statement and for the column `col4` simply `MAX()` (or `MIN()`):

```
select 
  col1, 
  col2,
  case when sum(case when col3 = 'AB' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 then 'AB' else null end col3,
  max(col4) col4
from test 
group by col1, col2;
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dtEiDdu6Arn6VQTGwMXm4q/1).
Results:

```
| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 |
| ---- | ---- | ---- | ---- |
| 12   | 35   |      |      |
| 123  | 345  | AB   | 001  |
| abc  | cde  | AB   |      |
| ooo  | zzz  |      | 001  |
```

Comment: thank you very much. this solution works. I am confused at the `col3` part for `case when` condition. Can you please explain how this works when `group by` expects `aggregates` in the `select` statement?

Comment: This is the aggregation part: `sum(case when col3 = 'AB' then 1 else 0 end` and it checks if AB exists in the column. Then it is transformed to either AB or null.

Comment: +1 But why not use MAX(case when column = “ab” then “ab” else null end) more or less to simplify the Sum part?? Instead of using nested cases do i mis something here?

Comment: I agree with you. But what confuses me is that the **aggregation** `sum(case...` part is wrapped inside another `case when` which is not an aggregate. Shouldn't the outermost wrapping be an aggregation?

Comment: I think SUM() is more readable in this case as it resembles EXISTS.

Comment: @scientific_explorer the aggregation part: `sum(case when col3 = 'AB' then 1 else 0 end)` is there (this is required for group by statement). Then you can transform this result anyway you want.

Comment: @scientific after the sum() the value what comes out becomes more or less a literal “constant” for that record... Not sure if i used the correct term there annyhow literal constants are always allowed in GROUP BY queries like Select ‘1’ as number ... GROUP BY here i used the term correctly... thats why you can do the case on the Sum()

Comment: @RaymondNijland I couldn't phrase it better.

Answer (score 0):

This is a prioritization query.  `row_number()` is often used:

```
select col1, col2, (case when col3 = 'AB' then col3 end) as col3,
       col4
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by col1, col2
                                order by (case when col3 = 'AB' then 1 else 2 end),
                                         (case when col4 <> '' then 1 else 2 end)
                               ) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Your answer fails at the `123` `345` case. Can you check this out? It should give `001` for `col4` but gives `blank`

Answer (score 0):

Check This-

```
SELECT B.col1,B.col2,B.N_Col3,MAX(B.col4)
FROM
(   
    SELECT your_table.*,A.col3 N_Col3
    FROM your_table
    LEFT JOIN 
    (   
        SELECT * FROM your_table
        WHERE col3 = 'AB'
    )A
    ON A.col1 = CTE.col1 AND A.col2 = CTE.col2
)B
GROUP BY B.col1,B.col2,B.N_Col3
ORDER BY 3 DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select col1, col2, max(col3) col3, max(col4) col4
from
(
    select col1, col2, case when col3 = 'AB' THEN 'AB' ELSE '  ' END col3, max(COL4) col4
    from @table
    group by col1, col2, case when col3 = 'AB' THEN 'AB' ELSE '  ' END
) A
group by col1, col2
```